# How to perform explode inside json success function

Tags: jquery, json

I have a table field as **languagesknown** where it stores multiple languages separated by comma. But i want to show/select only the first language in my language field below. So how can i explode the field **languagesknown** inside the Json success function and display the data in **#language**.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function loadmemberg(m)
{
   $.ajax({
       type   : "POST",
       url    : "details.php",
       data   : {gvalue:m},
       success: function(data){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#name').val(obj[0].FullName);
            $('#place').val(obj[0].PlaceName);
            $('#language').val(obj[0].languagesknown);
            var obj="";
        },
      error: function(data){
        alert("Please Enter a valid details");  
      }
  }); 
}
</script>
<html>
<div><input type="text" id="name"/></div>
<div><input type="text" id="place"/></div>
<div><input type="text" id="language"/></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript equivalent of `explode` is `String.prototype.split`:

```
$('#language').val(obj[0].languagesknown.split(',')[0]);
```